# Make BOINC utilize all cores on raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, config, boinc

I have installed Boinc on a bunch of raspberry pi's. This is the only thing they are used for except for ssh access for configuring.

Running with default options only two tasks are crunched simultaneously.
This is evident, both with the "boinccmd --get_tasks" command which returns two current tasks, and the "top" command also shows two boinc threads processes 100%. This means two cores are running full load while the other two are idling.

I want to utilize all four cores, but do only have console access, so no BOINC manager.

I assume that the configuration in use is the /etc/boinc-client/cc_config.xml, and that the command to get the service to reread it is is boinccmd --read_cc_config.

I have looked over the config doc at https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/client_configuration but cannot find any switches that appear to do what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

`/var/lib/boinc-client/global_prefs.xml`
`/var/lib/boinc-client/global_prefs_override.xml`

Override will override whatever is in `global_prefs.xml`

Make adjustments such as changing `max_ncpus_pct` value from 50 to 100.

If your system allows 4 threads, then 50 would only allow 2 thread. Changing to 100, utilizes all 4 threads.

Restart boinc: `sudo service boinc-client restart`